# Struggling with limiting a RegExp negative lookahead

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a paragraph whose innerHTML contains text, some of which have words that are anchor links. I want to pick out word string matches that aren't contained within anchor links (enclosed in anchor tags) but I'm struggling with RegExp, my negative lookahead;

```
example(?!.+\</a>)
```

isn't stopping the lookahead when it encounters the start of another anchor link i.e `<a` so all words are seen as being inside anchor tags as eventually there is always a `</a>`.

How do I have a RexExp negative lookahead look for a `</a>` but stop when it encounters `<a`.

https://regex101.com/r/HTOgkG/1

Comment: Re the dupetarget that's been picked: In your case, you don't have to worry about the parsing part of it, because it's **already** parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML, HTML is far too complex for it.

You've said your starting point is a paragraph element. That means you already have a nicely parsed version of what you want to search. Look through the paragraph's descendant child nodes for Text nodes: For each Test node, see if it contains the word/words you're looking for, then look at its `parentNode.tagName` to see if it's in an `a` element (perhaps looping through parents to handle the `<a href="#xyz"><span>target word</span></a>` case).

For example, here my target word is "example":

```js
function findMatches(target, para, element = para) {
    let child = element.firstChild;
    while (child) {
        if (child.nodeType === 3 && child.nodeValue.includes(target)) {
            const a = child.parentNode.closest("a");
            if (!a || !para.contains(a)) {
                console.log(`Found in '${child.nodeValue}'`);
            }
        }
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }
}

findMatches("example", document.getElementById("theParagraph"));
```

```html
<p id="theParagraph">This example matches, but <a href="#">this example</a> and <a href="#"><span>this example</span></a> don't match.
```

That example uses ES2015+ features and modern browser features like `closest`, but can be written in ES5 (and `closest` can be polyfilled).

Answer (score 0):

```
<\s*a\s*[^<]*?>[^>]*>?<\s*\/a\s*>
```

[the example](https://regex101.com/r/FDOlET/2)
It just removes everything between `<a></a>`, it didn't remove the punctuations.

**[Update]**
Now it will not be stopped by `<a` or not closed `<a>` `</a>`

Comment: ...and it fails as soon as you have an attribute on the `a` tag containing a `>` character. Which is why you [don't try to use a simple regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454). Every time someone thinks "Yeah, but my example is really well-contained and simple." it ends up breaking. Every. Single. Time.

Comment: Yes I agree you should not try to use regex to parse HTML, this is correct if the context  **IS** HTML. If it's just a piece of text contains limited tags,  then maybe regex can help.

Comment: No, again, it isn't correct even for valid HTML: `<a data-foo="a > b">...</a>` fails, but is perfectly valid HTML.

Comment: It works here,  https://regex101.com/r/FDOlET/3, it removed everything you given.

Comment: Okay, so *this specific one* isn't susceptible to *that specific way* these usually fail. It's susceptible to this one instead: `<a>Go<span>ogl</span>e</a>` and probably several of the other usual way these things fail (including the ways you mention in your update). Again, this isn't in some way a radical notion. You **cannot** reliably deal with HTML with a simple regiex. It's just not reliable.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder totally agreed, it should not be used to parse HTML, it can only be used to do simple jobs in restricted context.

Comment: No, it can't, reliably. Again, this is not a controversial view.